# how to terminate a process in Git

Tags: git, bash, repository, readme

hi guys i was practicing git and i edited a file, i wanted to commit my modification but it open a message editor bash widow n i couldn't close it till i closed the bash terminal. i opened it again n wanted to reDo commit it gives me this message

[image: label]

how could i terminate this process, i removed the file n tried to creat a new one but still the same 
any tips?
thanks for your help guys

Comment: Please post the output of `ps aux | grep git` or similar to find out if there is still a git process running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete index.lock and don't create a new one

Comment: please elaborate how this help